# How to insert white space in a file path in .emacs file?

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I'm trying use mit-scheme in emacs but I can't get passed that problem...

The problem is I don't know how to add white spaces in a file path in .emacs file
So far I've tried

```
(setq scheme-program-name
"/Applications/MIT:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme")
(require 'xscheme)
```

and

```
(setq scheme-program-name
"/Applications/MIT:GNU Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme")
(require 'xscheme)
```

but the outputs I get is

```
Can't exec program: /Applications/MIT:GNUScheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme
Can't exec program: /Applications/MIT:GNU
```

because there is a white space missing in the path..

Comment: Double the backslash to insert a single literal backslash. This will then escape the space when you pass this string to a function that needs a path: "/Applications/MIT:GNU\\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme"

Comment: the output I get is now Can't exec program: /Applications/MIT:GNU\

Comment: Please provide some context - what function and/or variable are trying to use with this string?

Comment: I just edited for more context! Sorry I didn't know it was important, I'm a total newbie with emacs stuff..

Comment: Well, instead I used my alias in usr/bin/scheme* but if somebody has an answer I would be glad to hear it

Comment: Did you try without a backslash? In most cases you don't need a backslash when the path is provided as a string, as in this case. At least on Linux. Maybe it's different on Mac.

Comment: Yes I did, and it didn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible using the existing functions, due to the way scheme gets called. The function `run-scheme` contains an explicit call to the function `split-string-and-unquote` on the scheme program name. As a consequence, the path to the scheme program will always be split at the first space. This means it is impossible to use a path with a space in it.

This is a bug that should be reported to the maintainers I think.

Comment: Well Stefan Monnier is one of my computer science teachers at Universite de Montreal, I'll tell him :P! Thanks for your help!